# sublime text 3 auto indent tcl and python

Tags: python, formatting, tcl, sublimetext3

I starting using sublime text 3 recently, and I really love it.    I mainly use it for tcl, python, CMake, scripts (sh, bat), occasionally MATLAB, and some c++ (I would love to replace eclipse with it, but I have been unsuccessful so far in doing so). 
ST is the first editor I've found that has good support for all the languages I use and one of few that highlights and auto completes tcl. However, I have been having some issues with the auto indent feature (I love auto indent, I'm a lazy formatter...). ST3 seems to be indenting wrong for both tcl and python. My search hasn't led me to any solutions, so I'm asking here.

I have set (in user settings and keymap):

```
"indent_to_bracket": false,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true

{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} }
```

Here is an example in tcl (good followed by bad)

```
proc hello { args } {
    set var 0
    if { $var } {
        puts "$var again"
    } {
        puts "NO VAR!"
    }
}
proc helloagain { args } {
    puts "hello again"
}
```

after autoindent:

```
proc hello { args } {
    set var 0
    if { $var } {
        puts "$var again"
        } {
            puts "NO VAR!"
        }
    }
    proc helloagain { args } {
        puts "hello again"
    }
```

python:

```py
def hello(number):
    num = int(number)
    if num == 0:
        print "Number is nil!"
    else:
        print "number is "+str(num)
    print "now im quitting"
```

bad

```py
def hello(number):
    num = int(number)
    if num == 0:
        print "Number is nil!"
    else:
        print "number is "+str(num)
        print "now im quitting"
```

The python auto indent makes sense to me because the interpreter (or whatever does the auto indent) has no way to know when then if statement is finished, I have been using # to set the indent to right place in python.  However, this doesn't work in tcl, and moreover the tcl interpreter computes comment blocks (you cannot have a un-closed { in a comment). It seems that the auto-formatting should have the necessary information to format tcl correctly, after all I'm specifying the beginning and end of blocks using curly brackets. I know this feature is a luxury, but I would love to get it working properly for these languages.

-Jameson

Comment: Does it work if you put an explicit `else` in there? It's optional, but recommended for readability…

Comment: Putting the explicit else does not help with auto-indent. I am curious if this is a bug in Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Yea I've tried that.  If you put the curly brackets on two different lines it properly indents, but that's not interpretable code. They need to be on the same line.